# How to connect a 4D display to a beaglebone

Tags: arduino, beagleboneblack

I am fairly new to all this so sorry if this question is rather trivial.

I have a 4D Picasso Display (28PTU-Pi) and I want to connect it to my Beaglebone board. So plugged the usb cable into the board and the splash screen came up. But how do I connect it so that I can actually run programs on it like the tutorial?

On the homepage I could only find this

[link](http://www.4dsystems.com.au/productpages/4DPi-24-HAT/downloads/4DPi-24-HAT_datasheet_R_1_1.pdf)

but that's for a raspberry pi and not the Beaglebone.

Sorry if this is the wrong environment to ask,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work. You can plug the display in via USB. And then run the tutorials when you set the commspeed of the program and the display to the same value as well as the USB port which by default on the BB is `/dev/ttyUSB0`